# IOS 13 doesn't play a notification sound using FirebasePushNotificationPlugin

Tags: ios, xamarin, notifications

I use Firebase to push notifications to the users at a certain time. They receive the notification but no alert sound is played. In the settings, the allow sound/notifications are turned on and other IOS13 and other apps play sound.

Version Number of FirebasePushNotificationPlugin Plugin: 3.3.10
Device Tested On: iphone X, OS: 13.4.1
Simulator Tested On: N/A (simulators don't receive notifications)
Version of VS: VS for Mac Community, 8.6.6 (build 11)
Version of Xamarin: Xamarin.IOS 13.18.2.1, Xamarin.Forms v4.6.0.847

```
AppDelegate.cs:

        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
 bool fbaseStarted = false;
            try
            {
                // This method does all the UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization() code so we don't have to.
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);
                fbaseStarted = true;
            }
            catch
            { }
            LoadApplication(new App());
            if (!fbaseStarted)
            {
                try

                {
                    FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);
                }
                catch { }
            }

            FirebasePushNotificationManager.CurrentNotificationPresentationOption = UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Badge | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound;
     }
```

Within one of the pages of my code, I subscribe a list of tags (please note that I unsubscribe because the first time the code runs it fails silently if the notifications aren't approved - resulting in the model thinking the notifications was subscribed when it wasn't):

```
               CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.UnsubscribeAll();
               CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Subscribe(Constants.NotificationTagsArray);
```

I keep coming across payload json solutions but unless I am wrong, I don't think that applies to me as I am using Xamarin and the FirebasePushNotificationPlugin. Is there any additional permissions that were added in ios 13 for playing notifications with sound that I have missed?

I have also posted here: https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/issues/348 but nobody has been able to assist me yet.

Thanks

Comment: You could test the app on an older version (like iOS 12.0 or before) . If it works , open the  
system settings -> **Notification** ->  **Your app** close notification and open again .

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I do not have access to an ios version between 10.3 (our minimum supported version) and 12 at the moment (though I am trying to source one) and I cannot use the emulators as they don't work with firebase. And no luck with turning the notifications off and on again unfortunately (I had already tried that).

Comment: It is also broken on ios 10.3.4 - eventually found somebody with an old iphone that wasn't too old and working!

Answer (score 0):

The issue actually lies with the sending of the notifications nothing to do with the Xamarin App. The issue resided in the services that sends the notifications to firebase (to then be sent out to the phones).

In the service we were sending a FirebaseNet.Messaging.Message() to the phones:

```
  Message FireBasemessage = new Message()
                        {
                            To = "/topics/" + PushNote.Tag,
                            TimeToLive = 86400,
                            Priority = MessagePriority.high,
                            ContentAvailable = true,

                            Notification = new AndroidNotification()
                            {
                                
                                Tag = "/topics/" + PushNote.Tag,
                                Body = enhancedMessage,
                                Title = xtitle,
                            }
                            ,
                            Data = new Dictionary<string, string>
                                {
                                    { "param", PushNote.Tag },
                                    { "text",  enhancedMessage} 
                                }
                        };
```

In the `AndroidNotification()` object required `Sound = "default"` to be added for it to work. Please note that this works for both Android and IOS notifications despite the fact it is an AndroidNotification object.